# Shutdown problems and wi fi not working on Acer Extensa 5220

Tags: wireless, shutdown

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS on an Acer Extensa 5220 laptop

After install I downlaoded all the updates suggested.

Two problems:

The in built wi fi does not work at all. I can connect to the network via a wired ethernet connection but the wireless network is not mentioned anywhere.

Second problem, on shutting down the screen goes blank, HDD activity stops but power remains on. Have to then press and hold the power button to turn off.

If I try going to suspend, the screen goes blank for a while, power stays on, then after a short while the screen comes back on inviting me to log in again.

sudo lshw -c video returns:

```
*-display:0             
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 03
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:44 memory:fc000000-fc0fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff 
ioport:1800(size=8)
*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
description: Display controller
product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2.1
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
version: 03
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:fc100000-fc1fffff
```

In the mean time sudo shutdown -h now stops any hdd activity but leaves power on with a screen saying UBUNTU and scrolling red / white dots under it.

I have tried using the software centre so search for driver. it says "no additional drivers found"

I did find in the software centre "Windows wireless drivers" which claims to be an easy way to install windows wireless drivers. but beg my ignorance, having downloaded it, I can;t find where it has put it to actually run it?

Comment: Add the output of `sudo lshw -c video` to your question.  Also what happens when you run the command `sudo shutdown -h now`.

Comment: I had the same strange shutdown misbehaviour on my Extensa 5220.
I had to push the "on" button long to really turn off the laptop.
After a few days this bug resolved spontaneously.
Maybe a software update fixed it?
Make sure you run all system updates.
Regards,
Michael